# Disallow workbook editing unless Enable Content is clicked

Tags: excel, vba

I'm setting up a shared Excel spreadsheet with macros, but I don't want to let anyone edit the document at all until they've clicked the "Enable Content" in the SECURITY WARNING bar at the top.

How can I "protect" the workbook like that?

Comment: Long story short, you can't. Someone could simply disable VBA on their machine so they don't even get the prompt.  An enterprising user could copy out all the contents to an unprotected workbook and make edits to that one and then save over the "protected" one.  Basically, Excel should never be used as a "secure" program because all of its protections can be fairly easily bypassed.

Comment: I'm not really that concerned with hackers, I just don't want them to edit the document until they've enabled macros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up the workbook to run a macro before the file is saved ([workbook.beforesave](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.beforesave)). In that routine, set all sheets to [xlVeryHidden](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/hide-sheet-and-use-xlveryhidden), except for one sheet where you explain that the user needs to enable macros. You could even have a screenshot showing what they need to click.

When macros are enabled, the [workbook_open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.open) event can unhide all sheets you want to show.

Protect the VBA project with a password.

Someone with very malicious intent and advanced coding skills will probably be able to find a way to circumvent this setup, but it should work well in a business environment where people just want to get their work done.

Comment: I like this idea, but I'm stumbling through my basic knowledge of VBA.  I will probably have 30 or 31 sheets in the workbook. Could you possibly give me some sample code?

Comment: Please use your Google Fu if the links I posted are not enough. We won't write the code for you. You've already written code for the workbook, so you know you can do it. The idea is to loop through all sheets in a workbook, and if the sheet name is not = "keep this sheet visible" then set the sheet to very hidden. If you have a particular problem, post it as a question with the code you have written.